# Deep linking like Spotify does

Tags: android, deep-linking

I'm trying to deep-link content to my Android app, and I've seen this pattern that Spotify uses:

`spotify:user:123456789:playlist:0n7j9BqAXsGvyXz70f98Ld`

How is that implemented and then received and parsed on the app `Activity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example that spotify is showing is done by using a [URI scheme redirect](https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-android-deep-linking-uri-schemes/), but another option is to use [Android App Links](https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-to-deep-linking-android-app-links/).

My suggestion is to use an open source SDK like [Branch](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking).